# Failure to add .dex while exporting signed apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I got this weird error when I tried to export my signed apk. I have no idea what the problem might be. I'm running eclipse as admin.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Stupid error]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my antivirus protection, I turned it all off and now it works.